# Address validation restrict more than 3 special character

Tags: php, regex, validation

I am working with validating address fields and I need some validation regex for decline more than 3 special character (comma)

**Valid format**

```
New York Marriott Marquis, New York, NY, USA
```

**Invalid format**

```
New York,# Marriott, Marquis,& New York, NY, USA,
$$$^^^&&&&&&,&&&&&########New York, NY, USA

preg_match('/^[^*|\":<>[\]{}`\\()';@&$]+$/');

preg_match('/[*|\":<>[\]{}`\\()';@&$]/');

preg_match('/^[a-z0-9- ]+$/i');
```

but all of those are not working as I need.

I tried with 
Any help will be appreciate.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Sure @Thefourthbird will edit question in moment.

Comment: More than 3 commas or more than in total any of `$^&,`

Comment: Okay I will try with it. Thanks :)

Comment: More than 3 commas or more than in total any of `$^&,` like [`^(?!(?:.*[$^&,]){4,}).+$`](https://regex101.com/r/R14XrA/2)

Answer (score 2):

Try using a negative lookahead `(?!` that asserts that what follows does not match any of the characters in the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) 4 times:

```
^(?!(?:.*[*|\":[\]{}`\()';@&$,]){4}).+$
```

[Regex test](https://regex101.com/r/G58fUd/1/)

```
$str = 'New York Marriott Marquis, New York, NY, USA';
preg_match('/^(?!(?:.*[*|\":<>[\]{}`\()\';@&$,]){4}).+$/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

[Php test](https://3v4l.org/rdnWJ)